# SharePoint And Excel Integration

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-object-model

I have an interesting problem. 
I have several Excel sheets that our users use to submit requests. We now want to automate them. We have created custom web parts and lists and got rid of the excel sheet.

However, many users are still using Excell sheet as they think that is the most convenient way.

I need a solution where I can allow users to download and fill details in excell sheet, and ask them to upload that sheet into a document library. 
As soon as the excel sheet is uploaded, we should parse the excell sheet, fetch the entered values and store them in a list.

Any pointers.

Hitesh V

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that SharePoint provides a DataSheet view? This is an Excel type grid you can use to copy/paste values from excel or enter them directly into grid to create new list items.

Read more about DataSheet in this article: [SharePoint 2007 : Use the Datasheet View to Add, Edit, or Delete Items and Files](http://programming4.us/enterprise/2402.aspx)